# Rstudio on Gentoo with qt = no workspace variable and file list text

Tags: qt, rstudio, gentoo

I'm trying to fix the problem of no text when I run rstudio at my gentoo.

My gentoo is configured with the necessary use flags to be almost pure QT5 desktop.

I have tested from rstudio-0.98.1091 (qt4) to rstudio-0.99.879(qt5)

My graphic card is GT-610 and I have installed the latest nvidia drivers for my distribution 361.28-r2.

I have set the opengl acceleration to the nvidia drivers and qt graphic system to native (hw acceleration), as well as the glx info shows direct rendering yes.

So I don't think that the problem is about opengl or graphic card,it must be a problem with some dependency.

[capture of rstudio, check the red square](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1cj8.png)

I have the following packages installed about qt:

```
[IP-] [  ] app-eselect/eselect-qtgraphicssystem-1.1.1:0
[IP-] [  ] dev-libs/libdbusmenu-qt-0.9.3_pre20140619-r1:0
[IP-] [  ] dev-libs/libqtxdg-1.3.0:0
[IP-] [  ] dev-qt/qtchooser-0_p20151008:0
[IP-] [  ] dev-qt/qtconcurrent-5.5.1:5
[IP-] [  ] dev-qt/qtcore-4.8.7-r1:4
[IP-] [  ] dev-qt/qtcore-5.5.1-r1:5
[IP-] [  ] dev-qt/qtdbus-4.8.7:4
[IP-] [  ] dev-qt/qtdbus-5.5.1:5
[IP-] [  ] dev-qt/qtdeclarative-5.5.1-r1:5
[IP-] [  ] dev-qt/qtgui-4.8.7:4
[IP-] [  ] dev-qt/qtgui-5.5.1-r1:5
[IP-] [  ] dev-qt/qtlockedfile-2.4.1_p20150629:0
[IP-] [  ] dev-qt/qtnetwork-5.5.1:5
[IP-] [  ] dev-qt/qtopengl-5.5.1:5
[IP-] [  ] dev-qt/qtpositioning-5.5.1-r1:5
[IP-] [  ] dev-qt/qtprintsupport-5.5.1:5
[IP-] [  ] dev-qt/qtquick1-5.5.1-r1:5
[IP-] [  ] dev-qt/qtquickcontrols-5.5.1-r1:5
[IP-] [  ] dev-qt/qtscript-4.8.7:4
[IP-] [  ] dev-qt/qtscript-5.5.1-r1:5
[IP-] [  ] dev-qt/qtsensors-5.5.1-r1:5
[IP-] [  ] dev-qt/qtsingleapplication-2.6.1_p20150629:0
[IP-] [  ] dev-qt/qtsql-5.5.1:5
[IP-] [  ] dev-qt/qtsvg-5.5.1-r1:5
[IP-] [  ] dev-qt/qttest-5.5.1:5
[IP-] [  ] dev-qt/qttranslations-4.8.7:4
[IP-] [  ] dev-qt/qtwebkit-5.5.1-r1:5
[IP-] [  ] dev-qt/qtwidgets-5.5.1-r1:5
[IP-] [  ] dev-qt/qtx11extras-5.5.1:5
[IP-] [  ] dev-qt/qtxml-5.5.1:5
[IP-] [  ] dev-qt/qtxmlpatterns-4.8.7:4
[IP-] [  ] dev-qt/qtxmlpatterns-5.5.1-r1:5
[IP-] [  ] lxqt-base/liblxqt-0.10.0:0
[IP-] [  ] lxqt-base/lxqt-about-0.10.0:0
[IP-] [  ] lxqt-base/lxqt-admin-0.10.0:0
[IP-] [  ] lxqt-base/lxqt-common-0.10.0:0
[IP-] [  ] lxqt-base/lxqt-config-0.10.0:0
[IP-] [  ] lxqt-base/lxqt-globalkeys-0.10.0:0
[IP-] [  ] lxqt-base/lxqt-meta-0.10.0:0
[IP-] [  ] lxqt-base/lxqt-notificationd-0.10.0:0
[IP-] [  ] lxqt-base/lxqt-panel-0.10.0-r1:0
[IP-] [  ] lxqt-base/lxqt-policykit-0.10.0:0
[IP-] [  ] lxqt-base/lxqt-powermanagement-0.10.0:0
[IP-] [  ] lxqt-base/lxqt-qtplugin-0.10.0:0
[IP-] [  ] lxqt-base/lxqt-runner-0.10.0:0
[IP-] [  ] lxqt-base/lxqt-session-0.10.0:0
[IP-] [  ] lxqt-base/lxqt-sudo-0.10.0:0
[IP-] [  ] media-gfx/lximage-qt-0.4.0:0
[IP-] [  ] sys-auth/polkit-qt-0.112.0-r1:0
[IP-] [  ] x11-libs/qtermwidget-0.6.0:0
[IP-] [  ] x11-misc/obconf-qt-0.9.0_p20150729:0
[IP-] [  ] x11-misc/pcmanfm-qt-0.10.0:0
[IP-] [  ] x11-terms/qterminal-0.6.0:0
```

And here are my use flags:

```
fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 \
ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc -gdbm cairo aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid dca sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm ida arat epb pln pts dtherm egl eglfs evdev -spell -lightdm sddm admin lximage powermanagement tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid cqm xsaveopt cqm_llc -adns -tcmalloc webgl cqm_occup_llc nsplugin uvm additions experimental bindist dri -sna udev uxa -xvmc -vaapi opengl intel -llvm -embedded -gpm -profile -berkdb -tiff -mariadb mysql -kerberos -rdoc nvidia pcre16 -gcj -objc* fuse archive gphoto2 mtp -cap -filecaps librsync-bundled -upower xscreensaver -mono fortran -test -webdav -client -ant vdpau acpi -laptop threads lm_sensors pmu apm -java alsa avi jpeg vba -system-wine lapack -exceptions -ipv6 -kde mp3 mpeg ogg -wifi xvid x264 aac faac usb X -arts -gtk -gtk2 -gtk3 ssl -netapi -gnome -doc qt -qt3 -qt4 qt5 -qt3support xlib-xcb minimal dbus lock policykit rar session -server sudo -subunit -ruby startup-notification thunar -cups -xa libkms curl -viaregtool -ads -acl -espeak -opencl -samba -winbind -smbclient -bluetooth dhcpcd -ppp -modemmanager -networkmanager icu minizip -sqlite -python symlink -wext -system-jsoncpp network-uri -boundschecks -https -system-ffmpeg -opus openvg webkit wxwidgets -xscreensaver ldap -sandbox ffmpeg ntfs -instrospection pdf -ppp pam -sendmail -kernel_linux -hangouts -geoloc svg -polkit consolekit introspection gallium classic webcam -video_cards_vmware -video_cards_nouveau -video_cards_radeon -video_cards_r128 -video_cards_tdfx -video_cards_vesa -video_cards_savage -video_cards_mach64 -video_cards_openchrome -video_cards_intel -video_cards_fbdev -video_cards_dummy -video_cards_trident -video_cards_mga video_cards_nvidia -video_cards_via -video_cards_glint -video_cards_v4l -video_cards_nouveau -video_cards_nv -video_cards_virtualbox animation-rtl -gnome-keyring cpuload colorpicker dom sensors worldclock
```

Any Help is much appreciated.

UPDATE: The problem is still present almost a year later , with rstudio-1.0.136 and QT 5.7.1...